# How can i embed SVG in JSF 2 Facelets (XHTML)?

Tags: jsf-2, svg, facelets

I have a JSF 2 application which creates some SVG content. How can i embed it in the output HTML?

The generated SVG looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="fill-opacity:1; color-rendering:auto; color-interpolation:auto; stroke:black; text-rendering:auto; stroke-linecap:square; stroke-miterlimit:10; stroke-opacity:1; shape-rendering:auto; fill:black; stroke-dasharray:none; font-weight:normal; stroke-width:1; font-family:&apos;Dialog&apos;; font-style:normal; stroke-linejoin:miter; font-size:12; stroke-dashoffset:0; image-rendering:auto;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!--Generated by the Batik Graphics2D SVG Generator-->
  <defs id="genericDefs"/>
  <g/>
</svg>
```

I want this output directly in the rendered HTML page. I don't want to use the `<object>` tag, because i want to be able to manipulate the svg content on the client via javascript.

The result should look like this:

```
<div id="svgcontent">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 50" id="myDIVBG">
    <defs>
    [...]
  </svg>
</div>
```

The above is correctly displayed in my browser, I just cant get the XML into the HTML without the XML string being escaped.

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you. For future reference: you need 4 spaces at the beginning of each line of code. The easiest was to do this is to paste in your code, highlight it, and click the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used JSF, but searching for "JSF disable escaping" turned up this:

```
<h:outputText value="???" escape="false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

What I have always done is edit my SVG files with a tool like inkscape and include them at the appropriate spot with a **ui:include** tag.   Like this:

```
<ui:include src="images/somedrawing.svg" />
```

The included file starts with an **xml** tag followed by an **svg** tag and the rest of the drawing. The size of the block on the page will be drawn according to the viewPort attributes of the svg tag.

This only works with HTML 5, so make sure your file starts with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works at least in firefox 7 even though the `<!xml>` and `<!DOCTYPE>` tags are rendered in the HTML body. I was hoping for a solution where i dont have to write out the file though, since its a dynamic jfreechart and i dont need to store it in general.

Comment: I will leave the question open for a bit, to see if someone has a solution that doesnt require writing files, if not i will vote your answer as solution.